# nginx 502 error unix path no such file or directory

Tags: django, sockets, unix, nginx, gunicorn

I am nearly finished publishing my web server, but when I search for the domain name, I get a 502 error, bad request.

When looking in the nginx error logs, I get this:

```
connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream
```

The problem is that the path unix is taking, is not correct, and I want to change it to:

`home/daniel/myproject/myproject.sock`

Basically I haven't find a solution for this problem while scouring the internet, and I will be very grateful for any help regarding this issue.

Comment: You need to edit your NGINX configuration file `upstream app_server { server unix:/home/daniel/myproject/myproject.sock fail_timeout=0; }`

Comment: @bdoublebleu I edited the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject`, with your information. I then restarted my nginx and gunicorn, but I'm still not sure if it's taking the new unix path, is there a command that will show me the path it's currently taking?

Comment: Did you move the conf into sites-enabled? `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject` then remove the default site `sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: @bdoubleu It worked! thanks for your help